# Quark state representation

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, quantum-states

Quark can be described by irreducible state representation
$\left|(R)Y,I,I_{3}\right>$.

What means these symbols?

I found example

$$\left|u\right>=\left|(3)\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right>$$

$$\left|\bar u\right>=\left|(\bar3)-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right>$$

Thank you for  explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "3" is the colour representation saying that it is quark in the three-dimensional defining represenation of SU(3), the $\bar 3$ is the complex conjugate colour representation for the antiquark, the Y is the hypercharge which is part of the electric charge, the I is the isospin representation and $I_3$ is the third component of isospin.

More details can be found in the wkipedia article on the standard model.